# How to print the exception in custom log messages when throwing Retryable errors to DefaultErrorHandler DLT?

Tags: spring-kafka

Ive implemented a KafkaConsumerFactory in which for the errors (Retryable error) I throw the exception. I want these exceptions to be printed an a proper logging format like sflf4j(LOGGER.ERROR) and not print on the console.
The ask is I want to print the errors in a proper log format instead of throwing in console with a huge stacktrace.

Below is the code snippet for KakaConsumerConfigFactory.java that has DLT Implementation to process and push error records to DLT topic.

```
package org.abc;

import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosException;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.exception.CosmosAccessException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

@Configuration
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

    @Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory, KafkaTemplate<Object,  Object> template) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new     ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        var recoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
            (record, ex) -> new TopicPartition("abc_dlt", record.partition()));
        var errorHandler = getDLTDetails(recoverer);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForDLT")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForDLT(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory, KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(3, 2));
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(70000L);
        return factory;
    }

    private DefaultErrorHandler getDLTDetails(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer) {
        var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer, new FixedBackOff(3, 2));
        errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(JsonProcessingException.class);
        errorHandler.addRetryableExceptions(DBException.class, DataAccessException.class);//Sample db exceptions
        errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        return errorHandler;
    }
}
```

Below is the class in which the error is throw from listener.java

```
@Component
public class Listener {
@Autowired
private LogUtil log; //Custom logger

public Listener (final LogUtil log) {
        this.log= log;

}


@KafkaListener(id = "hub_topic", topics = "hub_topic", groupId = "hub_topic_0", containerFactory =     "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", clientIdPrefix = "hub_topic")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {
        log.printLog("INFO",consumerRecord.value());
        saveToDB(consumerRecord.value()); //Method to persist obtained request to Database Columns                   //: id, String Payload-Consumer record
        ack.acknowledge();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the stack trace logs by setting the error handler's `logLevel` property to `TRACE`.

Then, subclass the error hander and do whatever logging you want do yourself after calling the super class methods.

**EDIT**

For example:

```java
@Bean
CommonErrorHandler eh() {
    DefaultErrorHandler eh = new DefaultErrorHandler((rec, ex) -> {
        System.out.println("Recovered " + KafkaUtils.format(rec));
    }, new FixedBackOff(3000L, 2)) {

        @Override
        public void handleRemaining(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
                Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {

            try {
                super.handleRemaining(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
                // log record was recovered
            }
            catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                // log retrying or recovery failed
                throw ex;
            }
        }


    };
    eh.setLogLevel(Level.TRACE);
    return eh;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary thanks for your response..could u please elaborate on how to subclass the error handler? If possible with a short code snippet..

Comment: I added an example.